# I am building an android TV application using flutter ,what are the best widgets I can use for remote navigation ,and an example would be appriciated

Tags: flutter, dart, tizen, android-tv

I am currently using Shortcuts widget but it id not optimal for a big application

Comment: Why is it not optimal for big applications?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.